# How to check if there is a row with same value combinations in a dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe and want to create a new column based on other rows of the dataframe. My dataframe looks like

```
    MitarbeiterID   ProjektID   Jahr    Monat   Week    mean    freq    last
0       583          83224      2020    1        2      3.875    4       0
1       373          17364      2020    1        3      5.00     0       4
2       923          19234      2020    1        4      5.00     3       3
3       643          17364      2020    1        3      4.00     2       2
```

Now I want to check, if the freq of a row is zero, then I will check if there is another row with the same ProjektID and Year an Week where the freq is not 0. If this is true I want a new column "other" which is value 1 and 0 else.
So, the output should be

```
    MitarbeiterID   ProjektID   Jahr    Monat   Week    mean    freq    last other
0       583          83224      2020    1        2      3.875    4       0     0
1       373          17364      2020    1        3      5.00     0       4     1
2       923          19234      2020    1        4      5.00     3       3     0
3       643          17364      2020    1        3      4.00     2       2     0
```

This time I have no approach, can anyone help?
Thanks!

Comment: Why is `other` in row `3` 0 and not 1?

Comment: @Timus I am not sure as OP could clarify but my feeling is it's dictated by freq column, as in row3 freq is not 0, I think OP wants to mark other as 1 where freq is 0??

Comment: @Timus Yes, because the freq in row 3 is 3 and not 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution tests if the required conditions are True.

```
import io
import pandas as pd
```

Data

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""
MitarbeiterID   ProjektID   Jahr    Monat   Week    mean    freq    last
0       583          83224      2020    1        2      3.875    4       0
1       373          17364      2020    1        3      5.00     0       4
2       923          19234      2020    1        4      5.00     3       3
3       643          17364      2020    1        3      4.00     2       2
"""), sep="\s\s+", engine="python")
```

Make a column `other` with all values zero.

```
df['other'] = 0
```

If ProjektID, Jahr, Week are duplicated and *any* of the Freq values is larger than zero, then the rows that are duplicated (keep=False to also capture the original duplicated row) and where Freq is zero will have the value Other filled with 1. Change `any()` to `all()` if you need all values to be larger than zero.

```
if (df.loc[df[['ProjektID','Jahr', 'Week']].duplicated(), 'freq'] > 0).any(): df.loc[(df[['ProjektID','Jahr', 'Week']].duplicated(keep=False)) & (df['freq'] == 0), ['other']] = 1
else: print("Other stays zero")
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to solve this is not to use pandas too much :-) converting things to sets and tuples should make it fast enough.

The idea is to make a dictionary of all the triples `(ProjektID, Jahr, Week)` that appear in the dataset with `freq != 0` and then check for all lines with `freq == 0` if their triple belongs to this dictionary or not. In code, I'm creating a dummy dataset with:

```
x = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 2, (8, 4)), columns=['id', 'year', 'week', 'freq'])
```

which in my case randomly gave:

```
>>> x
   id  year  week  freq
0   1     0     0     0
1   0     0     0     1
2   0     1     0     1
3   0     0     1     0
4   0     1     0     0
5   1     0     0     1
6   0     0     1     1
7   0     1     1     0
```

Now, we want triplets only where `freq != 0`, so we use

```
x1 = x.loc[x['freq'] != 0]
triplets = {tuple(row) for row in x1[['id', 'year', 'week']].values}
```

Note that I'm using `x1.values`, which is not a pandas DataFrame but rather a numpy array; so each row in there can now be converted to tuple. This is necessary because dataframe rows, or even numpy array or lists, are mutable objects and cannot be hashed in a dictionary otherwise. Using a set instead of e.g. a list (which doesn't have this restriction) is for efficiency purposes.

Next, we define a boolean variable which is True if a triplet (id, year, week) belongs to the above set:

```
belongs = x[['id', 'year', 'week']].apply(lambda x: tuple(x) in triplets, axis=1)
```

We are basically done, this is the further column you want, except for also needing to force freq == 0:

```
x['other'] = np.logical_and(belongs, x['freq'] == 0).astype(int)
```

(the final `.astype(int)` is to have it values 0 and 1, as you were asking, instead of False and True). Final result in my case:

```
>>> x
   id  year  week  freq  other
0   1     0     0     0      1
1   0     0     0     1      0
2   0     1     0     1      0
3   0     0     1     0      1
4   0     1     0     0      1
5   1     0     0     1      0
6   0     0     1     1      0
7   0     1     1     0      0
```

Comment: Thank you! I think there is something that exclude itselfs. I just got zeros in my column other, so there is never freq = 0 and belongs=True. I tried other cases that confirm that. But I don't figure out..

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I am too late ...:

```
df.set_index(['ProjektID', 'Jahr', 'Week'], drop=True, inplace=True)
df['other'] = 0
df.other.mask(df.freq == 0,
              df.freq[df.freq == 0].index.isin(df.freq[df.freq != 0].index),
              inplace=True)
df.other = df.other.astype('int')
df.reset_index(drop=False, inplace=True)
```

Comment: At SO it is never too late. Nice solution!